# Phar: re-use .htaccess-defined rewrite rules

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, phar

My PHP project has a dozen URL rewriting rules listed in .htaccess.

Now I want to provide the application as a `.phar` file and thus need to re-implement the rewrite rules the `rewrite` function that can be passed to `Phar::webPhar()` as 4th parameter.

Is there a way to re-use the `.htaccess` rewrite rules in my php code without implementing them in PHP directly? Some library/extension/code that just "interprets" them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before packaging up the `.phar` file, I generate a PHP array of regex pattern from the `.htaccess` file with [build-rewritemap.php](https://github.com/cweiske/phorkie/blob/master/scripts/build-rewritemap.php).

The rewrite handler of `Phar::webPhar()` then iterates over that array and tries to match:
https://github.com/cweiske/phorkie/blob/90f0bc1550eb0e5291f215552b22143fbe5e9398/src/stub-phar.php#L59